# How can I change the order of author, year, title, and publisher on bibliography with natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

By default, bibtex would put the year in the end. But how to change the order, so the year placed after the author? Like this:

```
Author. 2020. This is The Title of The Book. City: Publisher.
```

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Whatever}
    \blindtext
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{dafpus}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@book{DK86,
    author = {D.E. Knuth},
year = 1986,
    title = {The {\TeX}book,
    publisher = {Addison Wesley},
}

@article{DK89,
    author = "D.E. Knuth",
 year = 1989,
    title = {Typesetting Concrete Mathematics},
    journal = {TUGboat},
    volume = {10},
    number = {1},
    pages = {31--36},
}
```

Comment: You can load an appropriate bibtex style or you can create your own with `makebst`. To use `makebst` you can run `(pdf)latex` from the command line with `pdflatex makebst`.

Comment: @Guido that sounds complicated to me. I'm a newbie btw.

Comment: You write, "By default, bibtex would put the year in the end". That's **incorrect**. It is *not* BibTeX that determines where the `year` field is placed. Instead, the placement of the year field is governed by the bibliography style you're using -- here: `plainnat`. If you don't like its placement choice, you should look around for alternatives which do place the `year` field right after the `author` block. Howeever, without knowledge of what other formatting requirements you may face, it's not really helpful to mention possible alternatives at this stage.